# Jekyll image resizing with CloudCannon

Tags: jekyll, image-resizing, cloudcannon

I'm looking find a nice way to resize images uploaded by my client using CloudCannon.

I've looked at Jekyll plugins for doing this but they don't seem to play nicely with CloudCannon.

Does anyone have any tips or tricks for getting this to work?

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
<div class="section blog">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row blog__items">
      {% for post in site.posts %}
        <div class="blog__item col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
          <div class="article">
            <div class="article__head">
              <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}" class="article__media">
                <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.image }}">
              </a>
              <h3 class="article__title"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article__body">
              <div class="article__meta">
                <p class="article__date"><small>Posted on {{ post.date | date: "%d %B, %Y" }}</small></p>
              </div>
              <div class="article__text">
                {{ post.description }}
              </div>
              <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}" class="article__cta btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you just use CSS style rules, i.e. `width`, `min-width`, `max-width` properties for the `article__head img` elements?

Comment: @Jef I am currently doing this but it doesn't reduce download times if the images are large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an 'image resize service' or 'image resize CDN'.

I have benchmarked a few. They all work kind-of the same, but all have their specifics. Some are free, some not. Google even has its own unofficial free image resize service (somebody got the link?). [ImgIX](https://www.imgix.com/) is nice, but performed really bad at low-traffic websites when I tested it some time ago. They seem to have addressed the issue recently (2017), but I did not retest it.

For low-traffic websites I recommend to use the free [images.weserv.nl](https://images.weserv.nl/).

To use this solution, replace this part:

```
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.image }}">
```

with this:

```
<img src="//images.weserv.nl?url={{ site.baseurl | replace:'http://','' }}{{ post.image }}&w=600">
```

This will create a default compressed image with a width of 600 pixels, with a quality setting of 85% (if jpg). For more info, see the [documentation](https://images.weserv.nl/).

Note that with images.weserv.nl you will have only one shot at creating the resized image. There is no option to change or clear the cache if the request failed (or the image changed). The cache will automatically be deleted/expire in a month or so.

Comment: Thanks Joost. How reliable have you found this service to be? Have you ever had images not show up on your sites because the service is down?

Comment: I never experienced that so far (using it for over a year now), but I share your concern. For one website I have created an extra caching server, which I called a low-traffic CDN, but is basically an origin protector. That might be the way to give you back control over the uptime.

Answer (score 3):

CEO of CloudCannon here. We find a lot of people are running into problems with image sizing. Joost's suggestion is great and is the best answer we have right now.

With that said we are working on a way to resize images on upload which we think is a better solution for a couple of reasons:

1. Large images won't bloat your repository as much
2. There's no need to rely on a 3rd party to resize them on the live site

If you'd like for information feel free to get in touch with our support :-)

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your input. This would be ideal. Do you have any idea when we can expect this kind of functionality?

Comment: This is great news. I would absolutely love that! Looking forward to it.

Comment: Hopefully in the next month or two!

Comment: The feature has arrived! See: https://docs.cloudcannon.com/editing/options/#image-uploads. CloudCannon can now resize images. Thanks Mike!